# Why do I get nil when passing values through params in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<% if current_user.blank? %>
<%tripowner=User.find_by_id(@trip.userid).id%>
<%=tripowner%>
  <h3 class="text-center">Please sign up to provide recommendations.</h3>
    <%= form_tag usersback_url, class: "form-signin", method: 'post' do %>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">SIGN UP</h2>
    <div>
      <%= text_field_tag :first_name, nil, class: "input-block-level", placeholder: "First" %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= text_field_tag :last_name, nil, class: "input-block-level", placeholder: "Last"  %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= email_field_tag :email, nil, class: "input-block-level", placeholder: "Email address"  %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, class: "input-block-level", placeholder: "Password"  %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= password_field_tag :password_confirmation, nil, class: "input-block-level", placeholder: "Confirm Password"  %>
    </div>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :tripowner, value: tripowner %>
    <div>
      <%= submit_tag "SIGN UP", :class => 'btn btn-large btn-success' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<%end%>
```

`:tripowner` is not passing through the params correctly, but is returning nil.  I am trying to do this with it in the action.  I have confirmed that `tripowner` yields 1.  Therefore, I want `@friendship.f2` to be 1.  Is there a reason why it's returning nil below?

```
def createback

@user = User.new
@user.first_name = params[:first_name]
@user.last_name = params[:last_name]
@user.email = params[:email]
@user.password = params[:password]
@user.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]

@friendship = Friend.new
@friendship.f2 = params[:tripowner]
if @user.save

@friendship.f1 = @user.id
@friendship.confirmed = true
@friendship.save

reset_session
session[:user_id] = @user.id

redirect_to :back, notice: "Signed up successfully."

else
  render 'new'
end
```

end

friend model

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

params: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BkVY0/z0KeCQRg83wvumUKEmT67R4liMZr33u98mTBE=", "first_name"=>"rki", "last_name"=>"rki", "email"=>"test@k", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "tripowner"=>"{:value=>1}", "commit"=>"SIGN UP"}

As you can see, the 1 is being passed properly in tripowner.

Comment: You should pass the *id* of the user and re-retrieve it in the controller. That said, doing DB lookups in the view is generally a bad idea--pass it in instead.

Comment: the variable tripowner returns the id.  note the .id at the end of it's definition.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that-one reason to use whitespace, btw. Still, if you have a form, the value will be under the form's params, not at the root level--you can determine where it is by actually looking at the params being sent in. If it's not being sent in, or it's missing, then as Manoj said you'll need to set the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up associations so that you can access the trip owner via association, rather than having to run a separate query for it.

In this case a trip should belong to a user, and a user should have many trips...

```
   Trip.rb  # model
   belongs_to :user

   User.rb  # model
   has_many :trips
```

With this in place you can access the trip owner via:

```
   @trip.user.id
```

Assuming your acting on a @trip, you shouldn't really even need to pass anything through a hidden field.  Otherwise specifying something like this should work:

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag :tripowner, @trip.user.id %>
```

== Update

With the new code you posted, you should be using form_for @user...  This will correctly namespace all the attributes in the form with user: {attributes}.  With this in place instead of individually assigning your model attributes you can do something like this in your controller action:

```
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
```

It would also be helpful if you dig into your logs and paste the params hash thats being sent to your controller action.  If your running this locally, it would be in log/development.log.

== Second Update

First check to make sure the params hash being sent to your controller looks correct.  If it does, its likely an issue with your Friendship model.

Docs on hidden_field_tag: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag

Comment: thanks davissp.  i will try form for.  out of curiosity, is there any way to get this to work using it how i have it now?

Comment: Definitely.  Could you post the params hash thats being sent to your controller?

Comment: Also another thing id like to see is the Friendship model.

Comment: params["tripowner"] returns a hash... So you can access the actual value via:  params["tripowner"][:value].

Comment: great catch.  i'm getting this error now.
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
for this line
@friendship.f2 = params["tripowner"][:value]

Comment: So instead of passing value: tripowner in the hidden_field_tag just specify tripowner and it should just work.

Comment: same error.  would the controller code still be '@friendship.f2 = params["tripowner"][:value]' ?

Comment: Keep referencing your params hash, that should help you a ton.  But if you switched to hidden_field_tag :tripowner, tripowner .  You should be able to reference it as params["tripowner"].

Comment: Also if this solved your problem, could you up / mark as completed?

Comment: Yes i will mark as solved.  Still having issue though with it saying 'no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer'.  Think I'm close.  Thanks for help.

Comment: It might have something to do with how you defined f2 within your model? You can try outputing tripowner within the controller by doing:  Rails.logger.info(params["tripowner"]) to see if its getting the correct value.  If the error is propping up during value assignment then its likely your Friend model.

Comment: If your friend model is blank, try adding an attr_accessor: :f2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :tripowner, value: tripowner %>
```

I think you should use `tripowner_id` instead of `tripowner` just to follow Rails' conventions, so it can be something like:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :tripowner, value: User.find_by_id(@trip.userid).id %>
```

Comment: That returned 0 instead of nil, which seems to be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Have you checked value of you variaable `tripowner` in your view?

Comment: Just try pass a hard coded value in hidden field once and check its getting in controller properly or not?

Comment: Did not work.  just posted full code.  Quite odd.  Thanks for the help Manoj